# Validate sequence of letters without position ordering using Regular Expressions

Tags: regex

I want to validate a sequence of letters with exactly one occurrence of letters.  The letters I want to validate are `B`, `R`, `$` and `C`.

One letter sequence can have one or more consecutive occurrences, but the letter cannot appear elsewhere.  For example, valid sequences are:

```
BBRR$$CC
RRBB$$CC
$$RBBCCCCC
C$$$BBBBRRRR
$BCR
```

Every letter must appear at least once.

In valid sequences are

```
BRC
$CB
```

This can be done using multiple or operations in regular expressions.  I would like to know more elegant solution.

Comment: Use regular expressions to recognize words, not structures. http://kore-nordmann.de/blog/do_NOT_parse_using_regexp.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply,so you are saying it is impossible to do this with regular expressions.

Comment: Nothing is impossible. But, IMHO, that's not the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex matches the *invalid* case.

```
^.*?([BCR]|\$)\1+.*$
```